# How can i make Gatsby's custom 404 page to return 404 status code

Tags: http-status-code-404, gatsby

I have a custom 404 page and its working fine. When the user has a non existed url, lets say `example.com/abcd`, they are redirected to the 404 custom page. But the 404 custom page has 200 status code, that is not good for SEO. And as I read some information, this is normal behaviour because the 404 page exists.

But is there any chance to make this page to return 404 status code?

Gatsby version is 2.17.11.